# Using JRuby Warbler, is it possible to generate a WAR that can learn its RAILS_ENV from an environment variable?

Tags: jruby, warbler

Warbler wants you to specify a RAILS_ENV when creating the WAR. This is then put inside the web.xml of the generated WAR.

However, if you could create a wAR that learned its RAILS_ENV from the environment, you could create one WAR that could be used for staging or production - in other words, a superior management regime where a WAR can be tested and then deployed without being changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JRuby-Rack is already set up to read from RAILS_ENV before what gets put in web.xml, so that part is golden. The only thing you need to defeat is this `rails.erb` template that gets merged into a `META-INF/init.rb` inside the war file:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = '<%= config.webxml.rails.env %>'
```

There isn't a real good way to do this at the moment, but you can override the `Warbler::Jar#add_init_file` as follows at the top of your `config/warble.rb` to remove the Rails template:

```
class Warbler::Jar
  alias_method :orig_add_init_file, :add_init_file
  def add_init_file(config)
    config.init_contents.delete("#{config.warbler_templates}/rails.erb") if config.init_contents
    orig_add_init_file(config)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! BTW, what is purpose of the Rails template (rails.erb) in META-INF/init.rb? Will there be any adverse effect from removing it?